VoiceP internal subject hypothesis
In our class, we learned VoiceP internal subject hypothesis, which means the subject is firstly derived in Spec of VoiceP. But in some other textbooks, I also saw a lof of tree structures have the subject derived in Spec of VP instead of VoiceP, and the subject is specifier of the main verb instead of the null active, can anyone explain this point to me? Do we actually have two different hypothesis?
